# SQL Server Pooling vs Unpooling

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using mobile for sending data to a local SQL Server. My question is which is the best method to use? Also with best performance over network.

First method is to create connection string once and to opening-closing connection in each query.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = " + MyIp + "; Initial Catalog = xxxx; user id = xxxx; password = xxxx;Connection Timeout=3");

Btn.Click+=delegate
{
    string query="";
    query="Insert into Customers (name) values (dim)";

    con.open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

 }
```

And here is second method using pool

```
string connectionString="Data Source = " + MyIp + "; Initial Catalog = xxxx; user id = xxxx; password = xxxx;Connection Timeout=3";

Btn.Click+=delegate
{
    string query="";
    query="Insert into Customers (name) values (dim)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con))
    {
       connection.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I need best performance for using SQL Server over the network. Time is important for me, so which of the two methods to use?

Comment: Always the 2nd one.

Comment: Agree 100000% with @Igor. And you should wrap your command in a USING statement also.

Comment: ok thank you please write how is best way doing that, and i will accept answer

Comment: USING statements can be nested. Just wrap your command object exactly the same way you did your connection object.

Comment: Mehod above, is it correct?(Question modified),Also try,catch should be above sql connection or after that?

Comment: See the edit, that is how you can stack `using` blocks to reduce indenting.